# how to make multiple ajax callbacks from a drop-down field?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a select field in my custom module (Drupal 7), which needs to refresh the values of 2 different field types when a value is selected, firstly a checkbox field, which currently is refreshed correctly when am changing the dropdown value, and a text field, which is not changing, as it keeps the value from the first dropdown option by default.

Samples of my codes:

```
$form['webform_name'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
...
#ajax' => array(
  'event' => 'change',
  'callback' => 'ajax_checkbox_callback',
  'method' => 'replace',
  'wrapper' => array('checkboxField','txtField'),
)

$form['checkboxField'] = array(    
'#type' => 'checkboxes',
...
'#prefix' => '<div id="checkboxField">',
'#suffix' => '</div>',

$form['txtField']=array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
...
'#prefix' => '<div id="txtField">',
'#suffix' => '</div>',


function ajax_checkbox_callback($form, &$form_state) {
    return array(
    '#type' => 'ajax',
    '#commands' => array(
    ajax_command_replace("#checkboxField", render($form['checkboxField'])),
    ajax_command_replace("#txtField", render($form['txtField']))
    )
  ); 
}
```

How can I make the `txtField` field to clear and load the corresponding value every time I change my drop-down values?

Answer (score 3):

In your ajax_command_replace where the form is rendered, do this: ajax_command_replace("#checkboxField", render($form['checkboxField']['values']=$text)), where $text is the value from the checkboxes, as shown below:

```
function ajax_checkbox_callback($form, &$form_state) {
    return array(
    '#type' => 'ajax',
    '#commands' => array(
    ajax_command_replace("#checkboxField", render($form['checkboxField']['values'] = $value_text_form_text_field_1)),
    ajax_command_replace("#txtField", render($form['txtField']['values'] = $value_text_form_text_field_2))
    )
  ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe `wrapper` should be a string and not an array. So can't you just change it to string :

```
wrapper => 'checkbox_textfield'
```

Something like above and change code to :

```
$form['checkbox_textfield'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div id="checkbox_textfield">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
$form['checkbox_textfield']['checkboxField'] = array(
  ...
);

$form['checkbox_textfield']['txtField']=array(
  ...
);
```

Comment: I tried the method proposed, but then my list of checkboxes stopped refreshing when changing my drop-down values. Any other approach for this?

Comment: I don't know if `'method' => 'replace',` is correct? Try to remove event and method too from the `#ajax` array.